# store procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_checklogin`(
IN username varchar(100),
IN password varchar(50),
OUT result varchar(50)
)

begin   

if exists (select * from student where tensv = username
    and password = password) then
    set result = "OK";
else 
    set result = "failed";
end if;
end
```

When i call sp_checklogin('vyvy','123456',@a);
[Result screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37PJq.png)

vyvy and 123456 is my username and pass in DTB, workbench no results
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your result is stored in the session variable @a.

After calling the procedure you should use

```
SELECT @a
```

to get the result